# iostream - linker error (using g++)

Tags: g++, gnu, gfortran

I need help!

I am getting following linker errors using g++:

```
`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
```

I need to call c++ function from FORTRAN program.
Simple example:
C++ function (func_c.cpp) is

```
 #include <iostream>
 extern "C" 
 {
    void cppfunction_(void);
 }
 void cppfunction_(void) 
 {
 }
```

FORTRAN function (programm.f90) is

```
PROGRAM fprogram

  call cppfunction()

END PROGRAM fprogram
```

To compile I used

```
gfortran –c  -c programm.f90 -o programm.o
g++ -c func_c.cpp -o func_c.o
gfortran programm.o func_c.o -o main
```

I'm using Ubuntu (Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-13-generic x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and gnu - 4.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to link with `g++` or to explicitly add the `-lstdc++` at the end of your linking command.

So either

```
gfortran programm.o func_c.o -o main -lstdc++
```

or

```
g++ programm.o func_c.o -o main -lgfortran -lstdc++
```

BTW, you should use a [makefile](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/)